# Weekly "My New Music" Playlist disappeared from Music "For You" tab

Tags: iphone, mac, apple-music

[image]Since three days or so, "My New Music"  Playlist has disappeared from my Music on any device whether it is iOS device or Mac.

The playlist is still in my library except that it is not shown in "For You" tab of Music app.

Does anybody is having the same issue? I'm located in Germany.

iOS version: 11.0.1
Mac version: 10.13

Comment: Can I ask you to provide some additional info. For example, you say this has been the case ever since three days or so ago - but does that timeframe coincide with anything else (e.g. upgrade to macOS High Sierra, upgrade to iOS 11, update to iTunes 12.7, etc)? If not, it'd be good to know what version of macOS and iOS you're currently running.

Comment: @Monomeeth I added iOS and Mac versions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would check your settings as they may have been reset, especially if you’ve installed any updates recently (such as iOS 11).

More specifically, go to Settings > Music and ensure that Show Apple Music is enabled.

Comment: Everything is enabled. Music is working as usual except the weekly "My New Music" Playlist has disappeared.

Comment: Also make sure that you are still logged in with the correct account (at the bottom of Settings->Music), especially if you use several IDs. I had to restart the phone to get it to work finaly

Comment: I checked my AppleID and I restarted the iPhone. Still the same. The problem is also on MacOS iTunes.